# AllureConfig output directory path NUnit3

Tags: c#, allure, nunit-3.0

I have created a simple test class and added `[AllureNUnit]` attribute to test class according to [this](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_nunit_3)

```
[TestFixture]
[AllureNUnit]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void CreateHierarchy()
    {

    }
}
```

I also created *allureConfig.json* file where I have configured an **allure output directory**

```
{
"allure": {
  "directory": "allure-results"
}
}
```

I am running my test using VS 2017...
The test has executed but I can not find anywhere a specified allure-results folder. Where is the allure-results folder?

As I undestand the specified directory is a relative path from some working directory.
If so then what is the default working direcotry and do I have a possibility to change a working directory? Or I need to configure an absolute path in the configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/issues/5), default working directory in NUnit 3.* is the working directory of console runner. So I could not find result folder using Visual Studio 2017. It is in somewhere system folder.

**Solution:**

We need to set either absolute path in *allure.config* or set working directory for NUnit programmatically e.g.:

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Init()
{
   Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location);
}
```

Then the allure-results folder will be in the `Environment.CurrentDirectory`